# Disable RMAN backups in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, rman

Recently I tinkered around with RMAN to see how it works, and somehow managed to get a regularly scheduled backup going. I don't really have the disk space or the need for RMAN to run, but I can't figure out how to stop it from creating backup sets. I think the original commands I used were:

```
$ rman target=/

RMAN> configure retention policy to redundancy 2;

RMAN> configure controlfile autobackup on;

RMAN> backup database plus archivelog delete input;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the job that has been scheduled is the automatic backup of the controlfile. That shouldn't eat up a lot of space, but you should be able to turn that off with:

```
RMAN> configure controlfile autobackup off;
```

Comment: i tried this a while ago and just checked up on it after a few weeks... no backup sets to be found!

Answer (score 0):

RMAN will only work if you tell him to. It doesn't have any scheduler.
The autobackup of the control files isn't done on a regular basis but on response to some events ( [see the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta010.htm#i1017491) ) and should not cause disk issues (a control file weights only some megabytes).

You must have something scheduled, using Enterprise Manager, the Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER and DBMS_JOB packages or the system scheduler.